# Telegram Client Open Source - How to change Project Name

Tags: android, apk, telegram

I have compiled the Telegram APK and tested it in my mobile. It is running well. Except when clicked the Location Icon (map) to be send, showing BLANK.

But if follow up with real send, its showing completely so other side can see the map.

Anybody mind to advise please.

Here is the AndroidManifest :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.telegram.messenger"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.LOCATION" android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.telegram.messenger.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="org.telegram.messenger.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission android:name="org.telegram.messenger.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <permission android:name="org.telegram.messenger.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/AppName"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TMessages.Start"
        android:name=".ApplicationLoader"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="@bool/useHardwareAcceleration"
        android:largeHeap="true">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCTNmNqbWovP9ETcAob98YlrfOQEAC0CJ4" />

        <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name="org.telegram.android.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="org.telegram.messenger" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="false"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what is your question and if it is related to programming.

Comment: How to show maps for the 1st time click, before send it to person we are chatting. Maybe a little bits of programming but maybe Google API Key related..

Comment: I am confusing how to explain, because I think the Telegram package already completed with all of the modules, so is that related with the Google Maps API Key or what, something like that.. any idea ?

Comment: You mean you build telegram apk on your machine and google map shows blank?

Comment: Correct. But shows blank just when I click Location Icon. Usually shows my location. But if I click SEND, the maps showing correctly in chat screen

Comment: Please have a look above, I have pasted  the AndroidManifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your problem from comments, you have to create `Google Maps API Key` using the keystore from your machine which you are using to build an apk.

1. Go to [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and create a project. Go to `APIs` and enable `Google Maps API for Android`.
2. Get your `SHA1` string of your keystore which you are using to build an apk. For default android debug key use something similar like this:

   `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`
3. Create an `API Key` using Google API Console and your app's package name.
4. And final step use this generated API key in your app.

That's it.

Comment: Yes I think so... will try. Sorry where do I have to write that keytool  command ... looks like the DOS command .. ?

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: accept what, sorry very new .. where to click.. ahh I can see in the left side

Comment: hi do you help me in changing telegram name of app from main users activity and all other activities . my question and block thats why i am asking here